# re.pl (Perl interactive shell) command history?

Tags: perl, perl-module

I just use perlbrew / cpanm to install Devel::REPL module, and would like to use its accompanied re.pl script to learn Perl in an interactive REPL shell under Mac OS X Mavericks. After entering re.pl and typing some simple perl commands, I tried to use up-arrow key or ctrl-p to go back to previous commands I just typed, but no luck, only got ^[[A or ^P keycodes displayed. Please help. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably need to install one of the `Term::ReadLine` modules.  See the docs for [Devel::REPL::Plugin::ReadLineHistory](https://metacpan.org/pod/Devel::REPL::Plugin::ReadLineHistory).

Comment: Brian, thank you very much. After `cpanm Term::ReadLine::Gnu`, the command history support for `re.pl` is enabled now.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like history is enabled through the [Devl::REPL::History](http://search.cpan.org/~ether/Devel-REPL-1.003026/lib/Devel/REPL/Plugin/History.pm) plugin.

Alternatively, I use perl -del which runs the debugger in a fashion similar to a REPL. I got the idea from this [post](http://perlmaven.com/using-the-built-in-debugger-of-perl-as-repl) on Perl Maven.

Comment: The docs seem to imply the History plugin isn't necessary just for up-arrow to work.  I find the debugger interface ugly and just do `perl -wnE'say eval()//$@'`.  Make it `rlwrap perl -wnE'say eval()//$@'` and you get history too.

Comment: @Brian, @j, both `Devel::REPL::Plugin::ReadLineHistory` and `Devel::REPL::Plugin::History` are already bundled with Devel::REPL, it seems that just running `re.pl` won't enable up-arrow to work, and what do I need to do to enable it?

@ysth, thanks for the tip. After `sudo port install rlwrap` and running the command you said, I got the minimum up-arrow command history support.

Comment: @j, I suppose that the perl debugger hack does not provide command history support.

Comment: @AlvaPan: the perl debugger itself will do command history if it finds the readline modules it needs, but people often seem to have a lot of trouble getting it to work right

Comment: These are some great alternative suggestions. Classic Perl TMTOWTDI.  The debugger has worked well for my needs so far.  I plan on trying the suggestion from @ysth as well.